# Subdivision surface modifier issue in Blender Guru Chair tutorial

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and while I was doing Blender Guru Chair, I came up with the following issue. Can someone help me out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not an issue, or at least I don't see an issue. The orange part is the original geometry before it's modifier by the modifier. Some of it is closer to the viewport camera than the resulting geometry, and that part is visible.

Comment: Is the merge not catching, in a _Mirror_ modifier? Please give a closer description of what the 'issue' is, and an illustration more indicative of it?

Comment: I agree with @MarkusvonBroady. This is the same effect that you saw in the question you asked earlier: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295971/how-to-remove-this-extra-edge-extrudes-outwards-along-the-entire-shape-in-blende where I requested that you share your Blend file so that I could confirm my suspicion.

Comment: @JohnEason Hi John. After that 1st one came down with an issue I tried to do it again as new project and then got stuck with this issue. I'll upload this one as well.

Comment: @RobinBetts Hi Robin, I'm sorry but I'm actually I'm new to Blender. So I don't even understand how to describe this issue.

Comment: I haven't looked at Andrew's tutorial for a couple of years so don't know if he mentions it in the tutorial, but you don't have clipping checked on the Mirror modifier panel which means that the two halves of the mirror aren't merging properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slight tear along the mirror plane, where, in places, vertices have not merged as requested in the *Mirror* modifier.

Unless otherwise instructed, the mirror-plane passes through the object origin. (The little orange dot.) Some  of the vertices that are supposed to be on the mirror-plane have wandered off it during modelling.

Some steps to fix:

- (Keyboard <kbd>.</kbd>) > set your Transform Pivot Point to '3D Cursor'
- In Object Mode, with the chair selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > 'Cursor to Selected'. That will put the cursor on the object origin.
- Edit Mode again, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> select all the the loops, inside and out, that are supposed to lie on the mirror plane.
- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. That will flatten all the selected vertices onto the plane through the object-origin, and then they will be close enough to one another for the 'Merge' on the *Mirror* modifier to catch.